# MS Exchange 2007 EWS CreateItem utf-8 fails when containing german umlaut in Subject or Body

Tags: xml, soap, character-encoding, exchangewebservices

when sending this request to the EWS (note the "ä" in subject):

```
POST /EWS/Exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; chartype=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Host: ...
Authorization: Basic ...
Content-Length: ...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Body>
    <CreateItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
                xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" 
                SendMeetingInvitations="SendToAllAndSaveCopy" >
      <SavedItemFolderId>
        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="calendar"/>
      </SavedItemFolderId>
      <Items>
        <t:CalendarItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
          <t:Subject>ITGeschäft</t:Subject>
          <t:Body BodyType="Text">...</t:Body>
          <t:ReminderIsSet>false</t:ReminderIsSet>
          <t:ReminderMinutesBeforeStart>10</t:ReminderMinutesBeforeStart>
          <t:Start>2013-08-06T12:31:57</t:Start>
          <t:End>2013-08-06T15:31:57</t:End>
          <t:IsAllDayEvent>false</t:IsAllDayEvent>
          <t:LegacyFreeBusyStatus>Busy</t:LegacyFreeBusyStatus>
          <t:Location></t:Location>
        </t:CalendarItem>
      </Items>
    </CreateItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I get an error response like this:

```
 - soap11:Envelope xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 -- soap11:Header
 --- t:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="8" MinorVersion="3" MajorBuildNumber="83" MinorBuildNumber="4" xmlns:t="http://schemas.m
icrosoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" /
 -- soap11:Body
 --- soap11:Fault
 ---- faultcode
        = soap11:Client
 ---- faultstring
        = Fehler bei der Schema├╝berpr├╝fung der Anforderung: Unerwartetes Dateiende. Die folgenden Elemente wurden nicht geschlossen: soap:Envelope. Zeile 28, Position 16.
 ---- detail
 ----- e:ResponseCode xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors"
         = ErrorSchemaValidation
 ----- e:Message xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors"
         = Unerwartetes Dateiende. Die folgenden Elemente wurden nicht geschlossen: soap:Envelope. Zeile 28, Position 16.
 ----- e:Line xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors"
         = 28
 ----- e:Position xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors"
         = 16
```

but when I send

```
...
          <t:Subject>ITGeschaeft</t:Subject>
...
```

it works, the CalendarItem is created correctly.
How am I meant to send non-ASCII characters?

Btw, the other way it works, GetItem transfers those special characters correctly.
The request is correctly encoded in utf-8. Also tried Iso-Latin1, got encoding Error.

Answer (score 0):

encoding the request and the xml in ISO-8859-1 works:

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```